# Prepare dynamic filters

Tags: c#, linq, filter

We are in process of preparing dynamic filters which will be used for filtering records. We just should be able to select an entity (Lets say Person) then define filters according to that entity selected.

The design is something similar to this.

[image]

So how to design such a filtering system which can be used with any entity and any property?

We need to use

1. C#
2. MVC 5

Comment: Probably use generics.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a dynamic filter feature using WPF, the way I did it was using LINQ To SQL ORM, using my DataContext I get all the tables and its corresponding fields (MetaDataMember) and used it build the UI

```
IEnumerable<MetaTable> mappedTables = DBContext.Mapping.GetTables();
IEnumerable<MetaDataMember> tablesColumns = mappedTables.SelectMany(t => t.RowType.DataMembers);
```

Then I build [Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) on the fly for each criteria the user created using the MetaDataMember and its property.

```
Type entityType = metaDataMember.DeclaringType.Type;
ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "t"); // t => t; t is the parameterExpression representing the Table type

MemberExpression leftStringExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, metaDataMember.Name); // t => t.columnName
```

And then build the conditions i.e, Expression.LessThan (etc) and keep building the tree for each criteria using the conjunction expressions( Expression.AndAlso or Expression.OrElse) for each criteria and then finally create an lambda expression [Expressions.Lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and pass it to .Where() Linq Extension method to get my IQueryable<> filtered values back and use it to filter the UI.

```
IQueryable<SomeTable> results = DataContext.SomeTable.Where(whereLambdaExpression).Select(selectLambdaExpression);
```

The reason I went with this approach was because the query doesn't get executed until the enumeration (results.ToList()) occurs, and the query is executed  in the DB server and not in the current application. LINQ converts the query expression to pure SQL statement and only the results are returned. It is pretty fast as everything happens in the DB Server.

I am not able to paste all my code as it pretty huge, but you get the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

I had come across this kind of problem and I solved it by compiling text as LINQ query and executing it on the data (collection) and collecting the result. It will not give you best performance as each time it needs to dynamically compile an assembly (I have used it with collection as big as 100K rows and works well). However, it is very flexible. You can perf tune it further. Code is pretty long so here is the [github link](https://github.com/amithegde/TextToLINQ/blob/master/TextToLINQ/DataFilterHelper.cs).

Here is the main idea:

- create a valid linq query expression as string
- compile it as an assembly
- load the assembly into memory and pass the input collection to the assembly
- collect the output and use it.

The github link I shared has a simple working application with samples and projections.